# Accessing the Row of a UISwitch in a UITableView

Tags: ipad

I Used Code Similar to This to add switches to the rows of my TableView. 
Once the switch is changed it calls switchChanged. But How do I access what row (which switch) was actually changed?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
switch( [indexPath row] ) {
    case MY_SWITCH_CELL: {
        UITableViewCell* aCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SwitchCell"];
        if( aCell == nil ) {
            aCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"SwitchCell"] autorelease];
            aCell.textLabel.text = @"I Have A Switch";
            aCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            aCell.accessoryView = switchView;
            [switchView setOn:NO animated:NO];
            [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [switchView release];
        }
        return aCell;
    }
    break;
}
return nil;
```

}

```
- (void) switchChanged:(id)sender {
UISwitch* switchControl = sender;
NSLog( @"The switch is %@" switchControl.on ? @"ON" : @"OFF );
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UITableViewCell` object that you are adding the switch to will be `switchControl.superview` so

```
UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell *)switchControl.superview;
NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```